# how make a changing URL to create a changing picture using setTimeout function. (with angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, switch-statement

I want to make a kind of commercial pop up that will cycle a number of pictures around every 3 seconds.

i made a div and used "img" tag to link the div to the assets folder.
the problem is how i will make the name of the picture change randomly?
so i made in the ts file a function that generates a random number between 1 and 9 and used it inside a function with a switch that returns the name of the picture as just as i saved it in the assets folder.

when i try to call the function in my html component, it says: localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/images//capitals/ 404 (Not Found)

this is the code form the html file:

```
<div class="changingPic1">
    <img src="../../../assets/images//capitals/{{getRandomCapital()}}"  class="changingImgEffect">
</div>
```

this is the code from the ts file:

```
public generateRandomNumber(min: number, max: number): number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
public getRandomCapital(): any {
    setTimeout(() => {
        switch (this.generateRandomNumber(1, 9)) {
            case 1: const bangkok = "bangkok.jpg";
                return bangkok;
            case 2: const beijing = "beijing.jpg";
                return beijing;
            case 3: const egypt = "egypt.jpg";
                return egypt;
            case 4: const jakarta = "Jakarta.jpg";
                return jakarta;
            case 5: const jerusalem = "jerusalem.jpg";
                return jerusalem;
            case 6: const mexicoCity = "mexicoCity.jpg";
                return mexicoCity;
            case 7: const nursultan = "nursultan.jpg";
                return nursultan;
            case 8: const rome = "rome.jpg";
                return rome;
            case 9: const sidney = "sidney.jpg";
                return sidney;
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to put all the images URLs in one array and only change the index with a setInterval. With your implementation the problem is that you are calling a setTimeout at every change detection and this will cause memory leaks and will have a strange behaviuor.

in the .ts

```
public currentImgIndex = null;
public images = [
"../../../assets/images/capitals/bangkok.jpg",
"../../../assets/images/capitals/beijing.jpg",
.
.
.
];

.
.
.

ngOnInit(){
  this.currentImgIndex = this.generateRandomNumber(1, this.images.length);
  setInterval(() => this.currentImgIndex = this.generateRandomNumber(1, this.images.length), 3000);
}
```

in the .html

```
<div class="changingPic1">
    <img [src]="images[currentImageIndex]"  class="changingImgEffect">
</div>
```

Always try to bind your inputs to a variable and not a function because that function will be called at every change detection cycle unless you specify another strategy.

For the 404 error check the path you typed, it seems that there is an extra / between images and capitals.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i completly understood your question but if you want to cycle images you can use @keyframes in your css

```
        .img-container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        .img-picture {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url("pic1.jpg");
            animation: changeBackground 10s infinite
        }

        @keyframes changeBackground {
            0% {background-image: url("pic1.jpg");}
            33% {background-image: url("pic2.jpg");}
            66% {background-image: url("pic3.jpg");}
            100% {background-image: url("pic1.jpg");}
        }
```

Comment: not exactly what i looked for but i learned something new. thanks!